# Unable to access cucumber Hooks @After

Tags: java, annotations, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Cucumber 'After' Hook not working for me.
I am having BaseClass which initialize the driver.

```
public class BaseClass {
public  WebDriver driver ;

protected  BaseClass () {
    InitialiseParameter();
    InitialiseDriver();
}
```

We are having another class which is PageBase which is extended by other class which are having the Step-definition code.

```
public abstract class PageBase {
public WebDriver driver = null;

public PageBase(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
```

we are extending the PageBase Class as flow:

```
public class Search_TransmissionLines extends PageBase{


public Search_TransmissionLines(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

PhotoGallary photogallary =new PhotoGallary(driver);
Utilities util = new Utilities(driver);
```

The code is working fine for feature files all the steps are executed successfully but when it comes to execution of `@After` hooks it fails. I have created hooks class for it

```
public class Hooks extends PageBase{

public Hooks(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}
@After
public void CloseBrowser() {
    BaseClass.isBrowserOpened = false;
    driver.quit(); 
}
```

}
It displays the following error:
**Error:**

```
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: com.qsi.arcgisservice.Hooks has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver' for constructor 'public com.qsi.arcgisservice.Hooks(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@2cfbeac4:14<|

    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:191)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.access$100(ConstructorInjector.java:51)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:331)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
```

I am using java and cucumber v4, executing it with JUnit test.

Not sure what is breaking, can somebody please help me on this...so if there is any alternative that also works for me.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have added pico container to your path. If you do not intend to inject your dependencies using pico container then you can remove this dependency from your pom and they try again

`    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: I require the pico container..for dependency injection

Comment: You have unsatisfied dependency of Webdriver. Try removing this. 
`
public Hooks(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}
`
Also, to me it doesn't look like you are using DI anywhere because you are extending classes